# Why can I not call the size() method on the execute() method when it returns a List?

Tags: java, list

Why does this not work?

```
    if ((List)query.execute().size() > 0)
```

Since `execute()` returns a `List`, I thought I could call the `size()` method on it?

Comment: By the way, when its returning a `List`, why are you trying to cast it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're casting the result of the `size()` method to a `List`.

Instead, try this:

```
if ( ((List) query.execute()) .size() > 0)
```

*Edit:* And yea, as Adeel says: Why are you casting it in the first place? Does `execute()` return an `Object`? Otherwise, you can just lose the cast.

Answer (score 5):

You need brackets to indicate what you're casting. Currently you are trying to cast the result of `size()` to a `List`.

Try

```
(((List)query.execute()).size() > 0)
```

Comment: Still, you added an explanation. That's better imho (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the idea of casting a `List` to `List` in the first place. Secondly, `Henning` and `Qwerky` are good in suggesting that.

My take is actually, to suggest you that its better to have the list into some variable. Because here, its quite likely IMO, that you need to use the `list` later in your code. If you are pretty sure you wouldn't, plase go ahead with these suggestions.